# Why does my "Hello world" program take almost 10s?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have installed the CUDA runtime and drivers version 7.0 to my workstation (Ubuntu 14.04, 2xIntel XEON e5  + 4x Tesla k20m). I've used the following program to check whether my installation works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void helloFromGPU()
{
    printf("Hello World from GPU!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World from CPU!\n");

    helloFromGPU<<<1, 1>>>();

    printf("Hello World from CPU! Again!\n");

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    printf("Hello World from CPU! Yet again!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the correct output, but it's taken an enourmus amount of time:

```
$ nvcc hello.cu -O2
$ time ./hello > /dev/null

real    0m8.897s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m1.017s`
```

If I remove all device code the overall execution takes 0.001s. So why does my simple program almost take 10 seconds?

Comment: what time result do you get if you run `hello` just on one GPU?  e.g. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 time ./hello`?

Comment: I think cudaDevicesynchronize() is taking time

Comment: this doesn't change the amount of time used. It's about 9 seconds

Comment: @MadhuKumar running the Code without cudaDevicesynchronize() leads to 0.00 user 0.98 system 0:08.29 elapsed 11%CPU

Comment: Then your compiler or system have got a problem bro.

Comment: Is it possible that underlying setup is taking so long? Usually its better to measure timing after first call to module (if module is lazy initialized).

Comment: @kwesoly i have tried sereval examples from the Nvidia Code Samples. Every CUDA call has the same behaviour

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: @talonmies My system has 64 GB of ddr3 ram

Comment: *"Every CUDA call has the same behaviour"* – _every_ CUDA call, or the first one in your program? E.g. if you call `helloFromGPU` a second time, does this lead to a total run time of ~20 seconds?

Comment: @Zeta Every first user call has this behaviour

Comment: @chris: It's usually a good idea to [add additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31160795/edit) in your post (e.g. the RAM size, first call, etc).  Please don't add "EDIT" or similar while doing so, the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31160795/revisions) shows what has been changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apparent slow runtime of your example is due to the underlying fixed cost of setting up the GPU context.

Because you are running on a platform that supports unified addressing, the CUDA runtime has to map 64GB of host RAM and 4 x 5120MB from your GPUs into a single virtual address space and register that with the Linux kernel.

There are a lot of kernel API calls required to do that, and it isn't fast. I would guess that is the main source of the slow performance you are observing. You should view this as a fixed start-up cost which must be amortised over the life of your application. In real world applications, a 10 second startup is trivial and of no real importance. In a hello world example, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to deactivate this mapping for testing purpose?

Comment: @chris: you could try using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to reduce the GPU address space to be included down to a single GPU. That might help. I don't know how to disable host UVA mapping.

Comment: You can also try setting "persistence mode" on the GPUs.   Use the `nvidia-smi` command, use `nvidia-smi --help` or use the manpage to learn about nvidia-smi.  It may help a little, however I think the lion's share is due to what talonmies has described.

Comment: You may also want to be sure that the nouveau driver has been properly removed from your system.  The [linux getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile-nouveau) gives instructions.  The nouveau driver can cause all sorts of strange behavior, and there is at least [one example](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/851393/cuda-programming-and-performance/first-cuda-call-takes-13-seconds/) where it created a very long GPU initialization time.

Comment: Enabling pm as @RobertCrovella said: in root, `nvidia-smi -pm 1`